# What would happen if the connection between the input layer and first hidden layer is not dense?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

What would happen if we do not connect some nodes of the hidden layer to input vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that The Input layer of a neural network brings the initial data into the system for further processing and the Input layer will pass the input features or data to the 1st hidden layer. If we don't connect some nodes of Input to the 1st layer, it will not get all the data or features of Input for training. 
Look at picture 1 & 2. Picture-2 is the Simple schematic of Predicting the Earthquake Magnitude Using the Multilayer Perceptron Neural Network. If we don't connect some of the features of Input to 1st hidden layer, it will not get all features of the Input and can not give the proper result or prediction of the Earthquake Magnitude.
But when we have Large neural nets trained on relatively small datasets, we can do this skip connection in the deeper layer by randomly dropping out nodes during training to get rid of the overfitting problem. and you can see that here [Dropout for Regularizing Deep Neural Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/) .

[image]

[image]